# Title strip not scrolling to next tab automatically instead moving as per the movement of the swipe gesture

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, material-design

[image]

Title strip which indicates the selected tab does not automatically move to the next tab on one swipe. It moves accordingly to the swipe gesture for instance if you swipe just a little strip will move just a little even if it indicating the same tab.

I want to implement tab layout in fragment as user will be navigating on this page from navigation drawer.

Xml code

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/aboutTabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/aboutViewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />
```

code hosting the xml

```
    public class AboutFragment extends Fragment{

    @BindView(R.id.aboutTabs)
    public TabLayout tabLayout;
    @BindView(R.id.aboutViewPager)
    public ViewPager viewPager;

    private View rootView;

    /**
     * Mandatory empty constructor for the fragment manager to instantiate the
     * fragment (e.g. upon screen orientation changes).
     */
    public AboutFragment() {
    }

    public static Fragment newInstance() {
        Fragment fragment = new AboutFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_about, container, false);

        ButterKnife.bind(this, rootView);

        setupViewPager(viewPager);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        return rootView;
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        AboutPagerAdapter adapter = new AboutPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new AboutUsFragment(), getResources().getString(R.string.str_about_us));
        adapter.addFragment(new MissionFragment(), getResources().getString(R.string.str_about_mission));
        adapter.addFragment(new ValuesFragment(), getResources().getString(R.string.str_about_values));
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

adapter

```
    public class AboutPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public AboutPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

What is causing this issue? Where I am making mistake?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the fragments are empty this behaviour is observed. So just add your layouts in the respective fragments and it will resolve the issue.